# ProxyPass by servlets?

Tags: java, apache, proxy

I know how to set up an apache server with ProxyPass. so that a client can connect to a specific url, is redirected to another url but does not recognize this, as his entered url just remains.

Do I have to use a apache proxy for this? Or can I somehow achieve the same result with a Servlet? Especially the forwarding without changing the browser url, so the user still thinks he directly accesses the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably [lots of Proxy Servlets available](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=proxy+servlet&oq=proxy+servlet), some with probably a richer feature-set than Apache's ProxyPass. But you usually want to have a robust server sitting *in front of your servlets* which is why people setup something like Apache and use ProxyPass to proxy requests to a local (or internal) servlet engine.

You don't need to use Apache. For example, you can use [NGinx's ProxyPass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) to do pretty much the same thing. There's also other modules besides Apache's mod_proxy to do this if you're concerned about load balancing.