# How to write a proxy pass in Grizzly Server without using apache or nginx

Tags: reverse-proxy, http-proxy, grizzly, java-websocket

I have two Grizzly servers running my environment. 
 1. Grizzly server (A) private(internal) with Web socket.
 2. Grizzly server (B) public server.

web socket client should access the web socket server via the **server B** .

Does anyone knows , is it there any configuration can be done in **Grizzly** (look like proxypass in apache) or how to write a **Proxypass Http Handler** in Grizzly.

*Currently I'm using grizzly-http-2.2.16*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProxyPass by servlets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837019/proxypass-by-servlets)

Comment: Thanks @Slim for ur input. I have to do this without another server( without using nginx or apache).

Comment: It's still the same question, with the same answers. The top answer links to lots of servlets you could deploy in Grizzly.